# Can an overheated flash drive be repaired and reformatted?

Tags: usb-flash-drive, repair

I accidentally left a 64G ext4 USB flash drive too close to the CPU air vents (sometimes 50-60°C (120-140°F)).

Now, when I insert it, ubuntu 18.04 continually produces this message over and over in syslog:

```
May  6 11:59:05 ray-desktop kernel: [1892479.053574] usb 2-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 14 using xhci_hcd
May  6 11:59:05 ray-desktop kernel: [1892479.079311] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=125f, idProduct=db8a
May  6 11:59:05 ray-desktop kernel: [1892479.079317] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
May  6 11:59:05 ray-desktop kernel: [1892479.079321] usb 2-2: Product: ADATA USB Flash Drive
May  6 11:59:05 ray-desktop kernel: [1892479.079324] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: ADATA
May  6 11:59:05 ray-desktop kernel: [1892479.079327] usb 2-2: SerialNumber: 28B25094401400EB
May  6 11:59:05 ray-desktop kernel: [1892479.082827] usb-storage 2-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
May  6 11:59:05 ray-desktop kernel: [1892479.084266] scsi host0: usb-storage 2-2:1.0
May  6 11:59:05 ray-desktop mtp-probe: checking bus 2, device 14: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-2"
May  6 11:59:05 ray-desktop mtp-probe: bus: 2, device: 14 was not an MTP device
May  6 11:59:05 ray-desktop upowerd[1009]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0
May  6 11:59:05 ray-desktop upowerd[1009]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-2
May  6 11:59:06 ray-desktop kernel: [1892480.379143] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ADATA    USB Flash Drive  1100 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6    May  6 11:59:06 ray-desktop kernel: [1892480.380355] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
May  6 11:59:06 ray-desktop kernel: [1892480.380816] sd 0:0:0:0: [sdb] 121241600 512-byte logical blocks: (62.1 GB/57.8 GiB)
May  6 11:59:06 ray-desktop kernel: [1892480.383370] sd 0:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
May  6 11:59:06 ray-desktop kernel: [1892480.383376] sd 0:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
May  6 11:59:06 ray-desktop kernel: [1892480.383878] sd 0:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
May  6 11:59:06 ray-desktop kernel: [1892480.389255]  sdb: sdb1
May  6 11:59:06 ray-desktop kernel: [1892480.390874] sd 0:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
May  6 11:59:06 ray-desktop kernel: [1892481.000924] usb 2-2: USB disconnect, device number 14 
May  6 11:59:06 ray-desktop kernel: [1892481.003373] sd 0:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronizing SCSI cache
May  6 11:59:06 ray-desktop kernel: [1892481.008951] sd 0:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK  
May  6 11:59:06 ray-desktop kernel: [1892481.008954] sd 0:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 07 39 ff 80 00 00 08 00
May  6 11:59:06 ray-desktop kernel: [1892481.008956] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 121241472
May  6 11:59:06 ray-desktop kernel: [1892481.009002] sd 0:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
May  6 11:59:07 ray-desktop systemd-udevd[28507]: inotify_add_watch(9, /dev/sdb, 10) failed: No such file or directory

May  6 11:59:07 ray-desktop kernel: [1892481.545306] usb 2-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 15 using xhci_hcd
May  6 11:59:07 ray-desktop kernel: [1892481.574764] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=125f, idProduct=db8a
…
```

Similar messages appear regardless of socket (e.g. blue, yellow).

It of course never shows up in `/dev/…` or `/media/…` .

Is there any way to resurrect it so it can be reformatted and reused, or is it (almost literally) fried?

Comment: sounds like the controller got overheated and died. I would replace the USB Drive, and learn from the mistake.

Comment: There's no published 'repair' method I know of; if you can reformat it with GNOME Disk in Linux, you may get it to work again. Maybe it would work, but you'd never really trust it, would you?

Comment: When data recovery professionals repair a drive (any kind, flash drives included) it is only for the purposes of data recovery. The cost is very high and considered insufficiently reliable for continued use. Replace the drive.